# When is the product of two functions concave?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

There are two functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ defined on the interval $[a,b]$ and I am interested in their product, $$h(x)=f(x)g(x)$$
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both positive, $f'(x)>0$ and $g'(x)<0$. **I would like to find further assumptions needed to ensure $h(x)$ is concave and has a unique maximum on the interval**.

My approach so far has been to look at what we need for the maximum to exist, i.e. $h'(x)=0$ for some $x\in(a,b)$ and $h''(x)<0$. This gives me two conditions:
$$g(x)f'(x)+f(x)g'(x)=0$$ for some $x\in(a,b)$ and $$g(x)f''(x)+2f'(x)g'(x)+f(x)g''(x)<0$$
The second condition can easily be satisfied by the assumption that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both concave functions, which I am happy to make. How about the first condition? How can this be satisfied other than by making an explicit assumption such as $\frac{g(x)}{g'(x)}+\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=0$ for some $x\in(a,b)$? And what does such an assumption really mean (how to interpret it)?

Comment: Why do you need $h'(x)>0$? The logarithm satisfy these assumptions for h and has no maximum, while being concave. The critical points are where $h'(x)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, this was a mistake. I have hopefully corrected it.

Comment: A continuous function on a closed interval attains a maximum value. If the function is concave, the maximum is unique. If you are not working with an interval, the counterexample of the logarithm shows that you need an assumption of the form you have in the question

Comment: I am working with an interval, but I would like the maximum to be an interior solution, i.e. I would like the maximum to be on the interval (a,b), not [a,b].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concave differentiable function $h$ on the interval $[a,b]$  has a maximum in $(a,b)$ if $h'(a) > 0$ and $h'(b) < 0$.  The maximum is unique if there is no interval of positive length on which $h$ is constant.  For that it suffices that $h'' < 0$.

Comment: How to ensure that $h$ will be concave?

Comment: $h''(x) = g(x) f''(x) + 2 g'(x) f'(x) + g''(x) f(x) < 0$.

Comment: Thank you. So, it looks like $h$ will be concave as long as $g$ and $f$ are both concave, and one is increasing and the other one is decreasing on the interval, as this ensures $h''(x)<0$. For completeness, I have one more clarifying question: while intuitively $h'(a)>0$ and $h'(b)<0$ make sense, is there some formal result that ensures that?

Comment: A continuous function on a closed interval has a maximum on that interval.  If $h'(a)>0$ the maximum is not at $a$.  If $h'(b) < 0$ the maximum is not at $b$.  So it must be in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Of course, this makes sense now! Thank you!